# Opera can't find find element

Tags: javascript, exception, opera

I tried running my website in a couple of different browsers. It runs perfectly in all the browsers like firefox, chrome and internet explorer.

When I tried running it in Opera it crashed on a `document.getElementById('loader-graphics').appendChild(ldrInstance.canvas);` call. It said the following: `Unhandled Error: Cannot convert 'document.getElementById('loader-graphics')' to object`.

I tried everything and it seems like opera can't find the `div` with id `loader-graphics`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I used the following html code:

```
<div id="loader">
        <div id="block-bottom"></div>
        <div id="block-top">
            <div id="etine-image"></div>
            <div id="block-mid">
                <div id="loader-graphics"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If it can't be found, it probably does not exist. Can you show us the code? I cannot reproduce the issue

Comment: did you try renaming div id? or maybe the problem is in the appended element

Comment: I tried renaming the id to `graphics-container` which didn't change anything. I think it's highly doubtable that the problem lies with the appended element since opera says the problem is within `document.getElementById('loader-graphics')`